# OnePageCheckout doesn't place order after update

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, onepage-checkout, upgrade

I've updated my Magento environment from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.3. As usual, I stumbled across a few problems. Most of those problems I'm able to fix after a while, but I've discovered a very strange problem that I just can't seem to wrap my head around.

I'm using OnePageCheckout for logged in users to pay their products (OneStepCheckout works fine). I can go through every step, but when I push the "Submit Order" button, nothing happens. I don't have any JavaScript or PHP errors.

At first I thought my form needed a form key, since that's necessary for newer Magento versions. So I added this line of code:

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

This didn't fix it.

I tried to echo the saveOrder URL with it's form key and check what happened when I went directly to that URL. The link told me that nothing happened because I didn't check the Terms of Agreements box (which I did).
So obviously I wanted to know what would happen when I turned the terms of agreements off in my Magento backend. 
It gave me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getFullCustomerName() in /home/users/tetesftp/xxxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php on line 238
```

I'm stuck right now. Where do I look? Usually it's a template problem as well, but now all the other templates (like RWD) aren't working either.

I hope someone can help me with  this! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that my environment was reading some of my old files, because I still had old files in app/code/local. I simply had to rename the Mage map in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether **getFullCustomerName()** exist in the helper file. 
May be the update was not done properly, Since the **getFullCustomerName()** function is not available in magento 1.7.0.2, you only have **getCustomerName()** and that is the undefined function error.

Comment: I replaced the entire app/code/core/Mage map with the code from the latest downloaded version of Magento and it still shows the same error. Also the getFullCustomerName method does exist.

Comment: Make sure whether you got a function getFullCustomerName() in the Mage/Customer/HelperData.php file and if so try flushing the cache modules if you use any.

Comment: The function is there. What do you mean flushing the cache modules? I did flush the Magento cache if that's what you mean.

Comment: Is it possible that the code is looking for the function in a different way?
This is calling the function: `'customer'        => Mage::helper('customer')->getFullCustomerName($checkout)` which you can find in app/code/core/Checkout/Helper/Data.php
and you can find the function itself in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/helper/Data.php